# Escape ( in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Im searching for the regular expression - ".*(conflicted copy.*". I wrote the following code for this

```
String str = "12B - (conflicted copy 2013-11-16-11-07-12)";
boolean matches = str.matches(".*(conflicted.*");
System.out.println(matches);
```

But I get the exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 15
>   .*(conflicted.*

I understand that the compiler thinks that `(` is the beginning of a pattern group. I tried to escape `(` by adding `\(` but that doesnt work.

Can someone tell me how to escape `(` here ?

Answer (score 7):

Escaping is done by `\`. In Java, `\` is written as `\\`<sup>1</sup>, so you should escaping the `(` would be `\\(`.

Side note: It's good to have a look at [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) that *returns a literal pattern String*. In your case, it's not that helpful since you don't want to escape all [special-characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

---

<sup>1</sup> Because [a character preceded by a backslash (`\`) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: Thanks. This works ! But can you tell me why it is \\ when it is \ for escaping other characters like "

Answer (score 2):

`(` in regex is metacharacter which means "start of group" and it needs to be closed with `)`. If you want refex engine to tread it as simple literal you need to escape it. You can do it by adding `\` before it, but since `\` is also metacharacter in String (used for example to create characters like `"\n"`, `"\t"`) you need to escape it as well which will look like `"\\"`. So try

```
str.matches(".*\\(conflicted.*");
```

Other option is to use character class to escape `(` like

```
str.matches(".*[(]conflicted.*");
```

You can also use `Pattern.quote()` on part that needs to be escaped  like

```
str.matches(".*"+Pattern.quote("(")+"conflicted.*");
```

Or simply surround part in which all characters should be threaded as literals with `"\\Q"` and `"\\E"` which represents start and end of quotation.

```
str.matches(".*\\Q(\\Econflicted.*");
```

Answer (score 1):

In Regular Expressions all characters can be safely escaped by adding a backslash in front.

Keep in mind that in most languages, including C#, PHP and Java, the backslash itself is also a native escape, and thus needs to be escaped itself in non-literal strings, so requiring you to enter `"myText \\("`.

Using a backslash inside a regular expression may require you to escape it both on the language level and the regex level (`"\\\\"`): this passes `"\\"` to the regex engine, which parses it as `"\"` itself.