# Error when attempting to use custom comparator in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io, comparator

I am trying to create a class that reads a text file with each line having the same format, "#order) score - Name". I want to be able to read each line from a file and store it in an array, and then sort it by the highest score. I was able to accomplish this when it was just "#order) score", but adding the string to the mixture has complicated things. The error is

```
Scoring.java:46: error: no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<String>,<anonymous Comparator<String>>)
            Arrays.sort(scores, new Comparator<String>(){
                  ^
method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
    (argument mismatch; ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to T#1[]))
method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)
```

The text file is:

```
1) 10000 - Michael
2) 10000 - Jake
3) 10000 - Alex
```

and the class is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class Scoring
{ 
    private ArrayList<String> scores = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Scoring()
    {
        this(-1, "-1");
    }
    public Scoring(int newScore, String newName)
    {
        String highScoreFile = "scores.txt";
        String line;

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            File file = new File(highScoreFile);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String aScore = line;
                    String segments[] = aScore.split(") ");
                    aScore = segments[segments.length - 1];
                    scores.add(aScore);
                }
                if (newScore != -1 && !newName.equals("-1"));
                {
                    scores.add(newScore + " - " + newName);
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores.toArray()));
                Arrays.sort(scores, new Comparator<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2)
                    {
                        return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
                    }
                });

                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try
                {
                    File file = new File(highScoreFile);
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
                {
                    fnfe.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++)
                {
                    writer.write((i + 1) + ") ");
                    writer.write(scores.get(i) + "\n");
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores.toArray()));
                reader.close();
                writer.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scoring score = new Scoring();


    }
}
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't change your question into new one. If you have new problem, even if it is related to already posted code you should ask about it in [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Anyway `NumberFormatException: For input string: "200 - Jake"` is quite clear. You tried to use `Integer.parseInt` on string `"200 - Jake"` which as whole is not valid number. You probably wanted only parse part `200` so you need to separate it from that string.

Comment: I'm not following, if I separate the 200 from the string, then won't I lose the name attached to the number?

Comment: I am not saying to pass to Comparator only `200`. If you want to compare data in format `"200 - Jake"` then it is fine and you can pass it to Comparatior, but then it will be Comparator's job to select only numeric part from passed data and compare only that part. So instead of parsing whole text from o1, o2 you need to parse only their pats, which you can get like `o1.split(" ")[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arrays.sort` is expecting `T[]` but you are providing `ArrayList` which is not array, it is a list which is using array internally to hold elements.

Use `Collections.sort` instead, or since Java 8 you can use `yourList.sort(comparator)`.

---

BTW `split` method is using regular expression (regex) as argument where `)` is one of regex [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special). If you want to treat `)` as literal you need to escape it (more info at [Escape ( in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677167/escape-in-regular-expression/20677251#20677251))

So instead of `aScore.split(") ");` you can use `aScore.split("\\) ");`

Comment: You're solution seemed to semi-work, but now it is throwing a new error which I will provide in the main post!